# Easy way to filter Infs in a scatter3 plot

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter-plot

Given the following code, how would one make the Inf values invisible in the scatter plot without color manipulation?

```
J = rand(20, 40, 5);
J(J>.6 & J<.4) = Inf;

% Plot a scatter matrix
shape = size(J);
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(1:shape(1), 1:shape(2), 1:shape(3));
scatter3(x(:), y(:), z(:), 4, J(:), 'fill');
```

Comment: @divakar ups, too easy. So `NaN`s are never plotted. Good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data that have `NaN` values are made invisible when plotting with MATLAB, which you can exploit in your case. Since you want to make the `Infinte` values as invisible, you can convert all those to `NaNs` and then plot them. Here you can take help of logical indexing to index into `Inf` element positions. Thus, the code would be -

```
J(isinf(J))=NaN

%// ... Plot J
```

Comment: Do you know by any chance how to achieve the same thing, when using the OpenGL renderer?

Comment: @embert Oh sorry, no idea about those topics.

Comment: Just noticed that this can be easily accomplished by filtering out the vertices before plotting via `x = x(~isinf(J)), y = y(~isinf(J)), z = ..` after converting `x, y, z` and `J` to single column vectors (`x = x(:)`).

Answer (score 0):

One method could be to change the values higher than a certain threshold to NaN (or any other number). I believe NaN values will not show up in your scatter plot. You can do this with the same code you are already using.

`J(J>10^6) = NaN;`